# Quiero saber que se significa global.init_point en el SDK de Mercadopago Checkout

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, mercadopago

estoy teniendo problemas en entender que vendria a ser el global.init_point en la sdk de mercadopago checkout a la hora de reemplazar el valor de la variable $$id$$ en la data-preference-id del script que se encuentra en el form. Trate de debugearlo pero me tira undefined global.init_point porque no existe, ese atributo en el objeto global de nodejs no existe. Por eso no entiendo que trataron de hacer o que se significa ese global.init_point.

A la hora de crear la preferencia me funciona perfecto, hasta me trae el valor del response.body.init_point para reemplazarlo en el global.init_point, pero no me funciona el programa porque no existe ningun global.init_point

```
mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
    .then(function (response) {
        // Este valor reemplazará el string "$$init_point$$" en tu HTML
        console.log(response) // Me trae bien los datos
        console.log(global.init_point) // Me da UNDEFINED
        global.init_point = response.body.init_point; //Aca es donde vendria a reemplazar el valor de $$id$$ en el data-preference-id del script pero no lo hace 
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Este es el script en el cual deberia reemplazar el $$id$$

```
  <script src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js" data-preference-id="$$id$$">
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues entonces algo pasa con tu petición. El init_point es un parámetro que retorna el método de crear las preferencias, según cuentan en la [documentación](https://www.mercadopago.cl/developers/en/reference/preferences/_checkout_preferences/post/). Si tienes más dudas sobre cómo integrarte con MercadoPago, te sugiero contactar a los amigos de MercadoPago.

Allí indican que este es un HTTP response típico:

```
{
    "collector_id": 202809963,
    "operation_type": "regular_payment",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "picture_url": "",
            "title": "Dummy Item",
            "description": "Multicolor Item",
            "category_id": "",
            "currency_id": "[FAKER][CURRENCY][ACRONYM]",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit_price": 10
        }
    ],
    "payer": {
        "name": "",
        "surname": "",
        "email": "",
        "date_created": "",
        "phone": {
            "area_code": "",
            "number": ""
        },
        "identification": {
            "type": "",
            "number": ""
        },
        "address": {
            "street_name": "",
            "street_number": null,
            "zip_code": ""
        }
    },
    "back_urls": {
        "success": "",
        "pending": "",
        "failure": ""
    },
    "auto_return": "",
    "payment_methods": {
        "excluded_payment_methods": [
            {
                "id": ""
            }
        ],
        "excluded_payment_types": [
            {
                "id": ""
            }
        ],
        "installments": null,
        "default_payment_method_id": null,
        "default_installments": null
    },
    "client_id": "6295877106812064",
    "marketplace": "MP-MKT-6295877106812064",
    "marketplace_fee": 0,
    "shipments": {
        "receiver_address": {
            "zip_code": "",
            "street_number": null,
            "street_name": "",
            "floor": "",
            "apartment": ""
        }
    },
    "notification_url": null,
    "external_reference": "",
    "additional_info": "",
    "expires": false,
    "expiration_date_from": null,
    "expiration_date_to": null,
    "date_created": "2018-02-02T15:22:23.535-04:00",
    "id": "202809963-920c288b-4ebb-40be-966f-700250fa5370",
    "init_point": "https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/start?pref_id=202809963-920c288b-4ebb-40be-966f-700250fa5370",
    "sandbox_init_point": "https://sandbox.mercadopago.com/mla/checkout/pay?pref_id=202809963-920c288b-4ebb-40be-966f-700250fa5370"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si eso existe en la SDK Js pero seguro que si si es para el SDK de NODEJS, pero en la de PHP en esa variable se guarda la URL que se genera de puede de cargar todo los datos y se hace ...->save(); vas a poder recuperar la URL que pones en el link que luego llama a MP para hacer el pago.

En general es eso init_point dentro del SDK, pero fijate en la Doc aunque tiene muchos problema eso lo encontrar y esta claro o mira sus ejemplos para entender mejor.

Saludo espero que sea de ayuda y si fue de ayuda ya sabes regalame un check ;)